# Javascript ES6 Classes composition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, multiple-inheritance, prototypal-inheritance, es6-class

i'm struggling in what would be a good practice or better approach to communicate 'sibling classes in es6'  quoted because they haven't a real parent class, by definition.

let me explain better:

```
class Car {
  constructor(typeOfMotor){
    this.motor = typeOfMotor;
    this.mount();
    this.addListener();
  }

  mount() {
     // Some async logic here, and this will return true or false;
  }

  addListener(driver) {
    // Here i want to listen this.mount method and,
    // when return true, then call the ride method in the driver
    // If true:
    driver.ride();
  }
}

class Driver {
  constructor(driverName) {
    this.name = driverName;
  }
  ride(){
    console.log('Highway to hell!');
  }
}

class Race {
  constructor() {
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.car = new Car('v8');
    this.driver = new Driver('michael');
  }
}


var race = new Race;
race.car.addListener(race.driver);
```

So basically, i have some environments where i don't need to extend classes, because i want to keep them as encapsulated as possible.

And i have this top Class (not parent because the others are not inheriting anything, though).

And the question is simple, what would be the best way to create this communication between the elements.

Comment: There is no best way to do that. How you want to solve that depends on the actual situation. You could do a publication subscription or event based connection, use callbacks or direct access of the functions. Or a combination of all of them.

Comment: To me it seems that a race has one or more cars and a car has a driver. So an instance of `Driver` should probably be passed to `Car`. Of course you could also invert the relationship and say that a `Driver` drives a `Car`. It's really up to you how to model this.

Comment: But is not a bad practice these nested classes, right ? because i just see doc about the extend, but seems in my case that they don't need to be inherit by the others, just connected in good way

Comment: @t.niese can you explain me or give me some resources about 'publication subscription'

Comment: `extend` does not make sense in the shown code, because none of those types `Car`, `Race` or `Driver` have a relationship to each other that could be described as inheritance.

Comment: Not really. But your `Race` Object could deal as event broadcaster, and all Car and Driver Objects could publish events like `crash`, `stop`, `mount`, ... to the race and any other object like an Info object could subscribe for events on the Race and would be informed about events that happen with any Object that participates the race. Its basically just an event emitter and event listeners. But as I said that heavily depends on the exact use case.

Comment: *"But is not a bad practice these nested classes, right?"* I wouldn't call them "nested". But no, it's not bad practice. OOP is all about modeling "things" and their relationships to each other.

Comment: I agree with @t.niese: there is not a 'silver bullet' for this case. You can even use a more sofisticated pattern like redux to keep the state of the app in a state container and use reducers to 'change the store' after the dispatched actions and 'listen' to the changes. This is a more complex and powerful solution, but it's not indicated for most of the cases.

Comment: I don't see what makes these classes "siblings" at all. At best, they might be placed in the same library/namespace/prefix/modulefile - which is just that.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler funny part i was using React & Redux, but in order to fully understand the JS composition i started this silly but useful sample.

My first attempt is to execute the mount method through the Race, and pass the driver as an argument, works but not sure if there is a better way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `Driver` `class` instance to the `Car` `constructor` and invoke any method within this instance.

I would rethink the structure and business logic here and check what kind of responsibility each component should handle.
For example, i think it's up to the driver to decide **when** to drive but of course the car should signal when it is ready.
So the car shouldn't invoke `driver.ride` and instead just signal the driver i'm on and ready to go, and the driver should invoke the driving function.
But that's arguable of course.

Here is a running example of your code (a bit modified):

```js
class Car {
  constructor(typeOfMotor, driver) {
    this.motor = typeOfMotor;
    this.mounted = this.mount();
    this.driver = driver;
  }

  mount = () => {
    console.log('fetching data...');
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.drive()
    }, 1500)
  }

  drive = () => {
    // Here i want to listen this.mount method and,
    // when return true, then call the ride method in the driver
    // If true:
    this.driver.ride();
  }
}

class Driver {
  constructor(driverName) {
    this.name = driverName;
  }
  ride = () => {
    console.log('Highway to hell!');
  }
}

class Race {
  constructor() {
    this.init();
  }

  init = () => {
    this.driver = new Driver('michael');
    this.car = new Car('v8', this.driver);
  }
}


var race = new Race();
```

Comment: this is what i though, because is what i have been doing in ES5, but i was expecting another ways with some advantages or something like that in ES6. Thank you so much