# What are flexible approaches for creating different kinds or types of shape objects like rect- or triangles?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, factory, composition, es6-class

I have this code snippet that creates an array of boxes, I want to make it generic so it can also, for example, store a triangle. I'm not quite sure what parameters I need to use or how I need to modify this so it will allow a triangle. It almost seems like it would be better to create an array of triangles then position them to form a box if I want triangles and boxes, but then I'd loose the flexibility of creating easy rectangles. Context: this is a snippet of a program that implements a z-buffer.

```js
class Box {
  /** @member {Object} position of the box storing x,y,z coordinates */
  position;
  /** @member {Object} size of the box storing width and height */
  size;
  /** @member {Object} color of the box given in RGB */
  color;

  constructor (props) {
    this.position = props.position;
    this.size = props.size;
    this.color = props.color;
  }

  /**
   * Check if given point is in box
   * @param {Number} px coordinate of the point
   * @param {Number} py coordinate of the point
   * @return {Boolean} point in box
   */
  pointInBox (px,py) {
    return this.position.x < px && this.position.x + this.size.width > px
        && this.position.y < py && this.position.y + this.size.height > py;
  }
}

const boxes = [
  new Box({
    position: { x: 50, y: 50, z: 10 },
    size: { width: 150, height: 50 },
    color: { r: 255, g: 0, b:0 }
  }),
  new Box({
    position: { x: 80, y: 30, z: 5 },
    size: { width: 10, height: 150 },
    color: { r: 0, g: 255, b:0 }
  }),
  new Box({
    position: { x: 70, y: 70, z: 8 },
    size: { width: 50, height: 40 },
    color: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 255 }
  })       
];

console.log({ boxes });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Make *what* generic? It’s just an array; why can’t you add triangles to it?

Comment: Shouldn't a Box have also `length`, to make it actually 3 dimensional? After all it has x, y and z coordinates. If not, then it's a Rectangle instead of a Box. And if 3D shapes are intended, then maybe you mean a [Tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron) instead of a Triangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With vanilla JS you would have to use inheritance such as below. I would recommend using Typescript, a super set of Javascript, that makes using types a lot easier.

```js
class Shape {
  constructor({ color, position}){
    this.color = color;
    this.positon = position;
  }
}

class Cube extends Shape {
  constructor({color, position, height, width, length}){
    super({ color, position });
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.length = length;
  }
}

const myCube = new Cube({
  color: "#555555",
  position: {x: 12, y: 5, z: 9},
  height: 12,
  width: 12,
  length: 12
});

console.log(myCube)
```

In Typescript, it would look something like this instead:

```
interface Coordinate {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    z: number;
}

interface Shape {
    color: string;
    position: Coordinate;
}

interface Box extends Shape {
    height: number;
    width: number; 
    length: number;
}
```

And now, If I want a function that will work for both boxes and shapes, you can do it like this:

```
function getPosition(shape:Shape){
    return shape.position;
}

const myShape: Box = {
  color: "red",
  position: {
    x: 1,
    y: 4,
    z: 7,
  },
  height: 12,
  length: 12,
  width: 12,
};

getPosition(myShape);
```

Because Box extends shape, the function works for both of them, and any other interface that extends shape.

That's just scratching the surface of what you can do with Typescript.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize one could apply OOP type inheritances in JS. So I could have a Class Triangle that extends Shape; how do I communicate to JS to draw a triangular shape instead of a square or rectangular shape? Previously, I've drawn using this type of format: 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, not just x,y; however, for a z-buffer, I need the triangle in x, y, z format from what I'm seeing.

Comment: If your working with 3d shapes, you first need to make a function that can render any 2d shape, as a 3D shape is a collection of 2d plains. Then you can render any 3d shape, without having to worry about what shape it is. And the same with any 2d shapes. I'll add another answer with an example when I'm free.

Answer (score 1):

With Vanilla-JS one of cause is not limited to just one option like choosing an inheritance based approach. Composition, based on tailored mixins, does provide/support the flexibility the OP is looking for.

One also is free of where (and when and even how) to compose, for instance at plain object level within e.g. a factory function or at instantiation time within a class constructor.

```js
// function based "position" mixin.
function withPosition({ x = 0, y = 0, z = 0 }) {

  // "position" specifc (default) assignment.
  Object.assign(this, { position: { x, y, z } });
}

// function based "shape" mixin.
function asShape({ color='#000', ...position }) {

  // "shape" specifc (default) assignment.
  Object.assign(this, { color });
  
  // delegate "position" specific assignement
  // and default handling to the mixin.
  withPosition.call(this, (position || {}));
}


// factory function.
function createRectangle({ width=10, height=10, ...options }) {
  const type = {};
  
  // delegate "shape" specific assignements
  // and default handling to the mixin.
  asShape.call(type, options);

  // "rectangle" specifc assignments including defaults.
  return Object.assign(type, { width, height });
}

// factory function.
function createCube({ length=10, ...options }) {
  // composition via ...
  // ... "rectangle" specifc forwarding ...
  // ............. and "cube" specific `length` enrichment.
  return { ...createRectangle(options), length }
}

class Cube {
  // `Cube` type instantiation.
  constructor({ width=10, height=10, length=10, ...options }) {;

    // delegate "shape" specific assignements
    // and default handling to the mixin.
    asShape.call(this, options);

    // "cube" specifc assignments including defaults.
    Object.assign(this, { width, height, length });
  }/*
  constructor({ length=10, ...options }) {
    Object.assign(this, { ...createRectangle(options), length });
  }*/
}

const my1stRectangle = createRectangle({
  x: 50,
  y: 50,
  z: 10,
  width: 150,
  height: 50,
  color: '#fc0',
});
const my2ndRectangle = createRectangle({});

const myCubeComposite = createCube({
  x: 50,
  y: 50,
  z: 50,
  color: '#c0f',
});
const myComposedCubeType = new Cube({});

console.log({
  my1stRectangle,
  my2ndRectangle,
  myCubeComposite,
  myComposedCubeType,
});

console.log(
  '(myCubeComposite instanceof Cube) ?',
  (myCubeComposite instanceof Cube)
);
console.log(
  '(myComposedCubeType instanceof Cube) ?',
  (myComposedCubeType instanceof Cube)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @KillerSheltie ... check out a flexible, vanilla-js only and inheritance free approach.