# How could one refactor the implementation of two different types of sub classes while keeping both, functionality and naming of their methods?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, subclass, mixins

I have a single base abstract class that expects to be extended, which has defined a sole public method that uses a functionality expected from a subclass. Here, only `fullSoundSentence` is meant to be "public" - to be used by the outside world.

```js
class Animal {
    constructor(nickname){
        this.nickname = nickname
    }
    fullSoundSentence(){
        //expects this.composesound to exist
        return `${this.nickname} ${this.composesound()}!`
    }
}
```

I then have many classes extending it providing some core functionality (here they simply return a string but in reality they need access to `this`, modify properties of the object and so on)

```js
class Dog extends Animal {
    doessound(){
        return "barks"
    }
}
class Cat extends Animal {
    doessound(){
        return "meows"
    }
}
```

Another family of subclasses then uses this functionality, all in a different way. Kind of
"modes" in which we use the `Dog` and `Cat` functionalities. Theese modes provide the function expected by the abstract base method (`fullSoundSentence`), but they need to be a specific animal.

```js
class LoudAnimal extends Animal {
    composesound(){
        return `loudly ${this.doessound()}`
    }
}
class CalmAnimal extends Animal {
    composesound(){
        return `calmly ${this.doessound()}`
    }
}
```

Now, both cats and dogs can be both calm and loud. = *any animal can be in any mode*

Q: **How do i create a calm dog or a loud cat and so on?**

- I could create by hand classes for each combination (`CalmDog`, `LoudDog`, `CalmCat`, ...) but if there are more animals and more modes, this is terrible
- I could make the modes just object with functionalities that the abstract `Animal` would expect as an argument for example, but this is messy, especially if the mode also needs to modify properties and so on

**Isn't there some better way??** I'm looking for ways to do this in JavaScript or TypeScript.

Comment: The first design mistake is made when the `Animal` base type already does assume anything to be present from whatever sub type which does extend `Animal` whereas a base class always has to be agnostic about anything it does not explicitly provide itself or explicitly acquires via e.g. a mixin technique.

Comment: `Animal` is like a template. I wouldn't ever call `new Animal` except if I could write the constructor in a way that would allow something like: `new Animal(Dog, Calm)`. Thats what I need help with- the design. The modes and animals do not neccessarily have to be classes like shown in my example, Im just looking for the "most correct" way of doing things, so that later I can e.g. quickly and simply define a new animal and be instantly able to use it in any mode.

Comment: "*I have some base abstract class that expects to be extended*" - don't. Not everything needs to be a `class` in JS. Provide your shared functionality as a helper function. "*Another family of subclasses…*" - this is where you went all wrong. As soon as you have "families of classes", `class`es are the wrong tool. Use [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)! In your toy example, that might be an `Animal` class with `nickname`, `species`, `sound` and `volume` properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next provided approach introduces a toolset of **(a)** context aware functions and function based mixins *(which implement behavior that can not be provided in a meaningful way via a sub-typed class-hierarchy)* and **(b)** an `Animal` base class, some more specific animal sub types and also a factory in order to show that mixin-based composition can be applied at any time during and at any level of an object creation process (or an object's lifetime).

All implemented functionality got derived from the OP's example code, decomposed and re-assembled while keeping the animal type specific property and method names.

From the OP's originally provided `Animal` and `Dog/Cat extends Animal` code, in order to justify the existence of a base `Animal` class, and also in order to *DRY* both subtypes (`Dog` and `Cat`), such a basic type has to not only feature its `nickname` but also its `sound` property and its accompanying `doessound` method. `Dog` and `Cat` both rely on `super` delegation and are good enough for just providing the default values.

The rest is up to either a mix of further sub typing and mixin composition or to e.g. a factory which does instantiate a class and does apply specific behavior to an instance via mixin composition as well.

**Why is that?**

Both code lines ...

```
class LoudAnimal extends Animal { composesound () { /* ... */ } }
```

... and ...

```
class CalmAnimal extends Animal { composesound () { /* ... */ } }
```

... make no sense at all.

A calm/loud animal type is nothing which should/could be described in a meaningful way like in form of an entity which features a `nickname` and a `sound` property and a `doessound` method whereas a dog/cat can be described and recognized by these animal specific keys.

But there can be loud dogs and/or calm cats and/or vice versa. Thus, such types need to acquire specific behavior/traits like being calm/loud or expressing itself calmly/loudly. And this is what mixins are for.

```js
// sound-specific functions/methods (behavior) utilized by mixins.

function getBoundBehaviorDrivenSound(behavior) {
  // expects `doessound` to exist but does
  // handle it forgiving via optional chaining.
  return `${ behavior } ${ this?.doessound?.() }`;
}

function getFullSound() {
  // expects `nickname` and `composesound` to exist but
  // handles the latter forgiving via optional chaining.
  return `${ this.nickname } ${ this?.composesound?.() }!`;
}


// sound-specific function-based mixins (applicable behavior).

function withSoundingLoud() {
  this.composesound =
    getBoundBehaviorDrivenSound.bind(this, 'loudly');
  return this;
}
function withSoundingCalm() {
  this.composesound =
    getBoundBehaviorDrivenSound.bind(this, 'calmly');
  return this;
}

function withFullSound() {
  this.fullSoundSentence = getFullSound;
  return this;
}


// base-class and sub-typing

class Animal {
  constructor({
    nickname = 'beast',
    sound = 'grmpf',
  }) {
    Object.assign(this, { nickname, sound });
  }
  doessound() {
    return this.sound;
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  constructor(nickname = 'Buster') {

    super({ nickname, sound: 'barks' });
  }
}
class Cat extends Animal {
  constructor(nickname = 'Chloe') {

    super({ nickname, sound: 'meows' });
  }
}


// further sub-typing and mixin based composition.

class LoudDog extends Dog {
  constructor(nickname) {

    super(nickname);

    // mixin at creation time at instance/object level.
    withSoundingLoud.call(this);

    // withFullSound.call(this);
  }
}

// factory function featuring mixin based composition.

function createFullySoundingCalmCat(nickname) {
  // mixin at creation time at instance/object level.
  return withFullSound.call(
    withSoundingCalm.call(
      new Cat(nickname)
    )
  );  
}


const smokey = createFullySoundingCalmCat('Smokey');
const cooper = new LoudDog('Cooper');

console.log({ smokey, cooper });

console.log('smokey.doessound() ...', smokey.doessound());
console.log('cooper.doessound() ...', cooper.doessound());

console.log('smokey.composesound() ...', smokey.composesound());
console.log('cooper.composesound() ...', cooper.composesound());

console.log('smokey.fullSoundSentence() ...', smokey.fullSoundSentence());
console.log('cooper?.fullSoundSentence?.() ...', cooper?.fullSoundSentence?.());


// ... one more ...

class FullySoundingLoudDog extends LoudDog {
  constructor(nickname) {

    super(nickname);
  }
}
// prototype level aggregation / "class level mixin".
withFullSound.call(FullySoundingLoudDog.prototype);

const anotherDog = new FullySoundingLoudDog;

console.log({ anotherDog });
console.log('anotherDog.doessound() ...', anotherDog.doessound());
console.log('anotherDog.composesound() ...', anotherDog.composesound());
console.log('anotherDog.fullSoundSentence() ...', anotherDog.fullSoundSentence());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```